# Environmental Texture shows up only on object instead of the whole area

Tags: texturing

Sorry if this is a basic question as I am pretty new to Blender, My texture is supposed to show up like this[image]

but it only shows up like this
[image]

:O what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Hello, maybe show your Shader Editor, or even share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: How do you mean, your “texture“? I don’t see any evidence of textures in either screenshot, either image-based or procedural. I will note that in the latter one, the World shader is apparently not coming up with a “not found” error, but the object in both and the World shader in the first one apparently are, resulting in the violet color. As it is, this indicates that the second screenshot actually shows less problems than the first, so I have no idea what you’re talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're going for, but the reason the second image looks different than the first is that you have a *Transparent* background set -  to make the second image look like the first, un-check *Transparent* under *Render Properties > Film*:

[image: TransPareMag]

Like it has been said in the comments, magenta is Blender's color for "image not found" (you can see I have no image selected in the Environment Texture node) - if this is your goal, fine, but you probably want to select an image, else just change the color of the Background node (with no image connected to it).